# Adding items from a text file to QlistWidget in pyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I've been working on this code as part of my school project and i don't seem to be getting anywhere. My problem is when i try add the text from a file to my QlistWidget my program crashes. Firstly I want to know if this will add the files at the directory (each line in `movieDir.txt` is a directory) to the QlistWidget, secondly I'm not even sure if I'm using the right widget or if it should be QlistView. Also how would i make it so the currently selected item in the listWidget shows details in the text box (e.g. size of the file).

I'm also looking for this to be done on start up so if someone can please tell me where to the the `addItems(self)` that would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to using classes as we have been neglected to be taught this in school.

I'm running PyQt5 on windows 7

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'input.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.6
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(764, 500)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(764, 353))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(764, 500))
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(6)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralWidget)
        self.listView.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.listView.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.ListMode)
        self.listView.setObjectName("listView")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.listView)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_4)
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralWidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalSlider)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(6)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.dial = QtWidgets.QDial(self.centralWidget)
        self.dial.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.dial.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.dial.setObjectName("dial")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.dial)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 764, 21))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName("mainToolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.addItem)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Show Movies"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Fast-Forward"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Pause/Play"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Rewind"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Full Screen"))

    def addItem(self):
        with open('movieDir.txt', 'r') as movieDir:
            for row in movieDir:
                listWidget.addItem(row)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralWidget)
    self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
    self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.listWidget)

    with open('moviesDir.txt','r') as movieDir:
        for movie in movieDir:
            self.listWidget.addItem(movie)
```

This did what i asked, but it only shows it as text, is there a way to show the files at the directory instead of the directory as a string?

Comment: If you want real-time display of the directory, use `QListView` coupled with `QFileSystemModel`. Otherwise, use `self.listWidget.addItem( QListWidgetItem( icon, movie, self.listWidget ) )`. That'll show the icons as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
#This is the example code for loading files and content inside the file to QtGui.QListWidget
#It is PyQt4, but you can try with PyQt5 with small changes.
#If your are not expecting this answer, sorry.

import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):        

        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)        

        self.verticalLayout     = QtGui.QVBoxLayout (self)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName ('verticalLayout')

        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName('horizontalLayout')       

        self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName('listView')    
        self.listWidget.setAlternatingRowColors (True)              
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)

        self.verticalLayout1 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout1.setSpacing(10)
        self.verticalLayout1.setObjectName('verticalLayout')          

        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName('pushButton')
        self.pushButton.setText('Load File Content')

        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName('pushButton_2')   
        self.pushButton_2.setText('Load File')        

        self.verticalLayout1.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout1.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)        
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout1.addItem (spacerItem)

        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout1)        
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)


        self.pushButton.clicked.connect (self.loadFileContent)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect (self.loadFiles)    


    def loadFileContent (self) :
        openFiles           = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName (self, 'Open File', 'c:/', 'txt (*.txt)')
        if openFiles : 
            data        = open (str(openFiles), 'r')
            dataList    = data.readlines ()

            self.listWidget.clear ()

            for eachLine in dataList :
                if len(eachLine.strip())!=0 :
                    self.listWidget.addItem(eachLine.strip())                 


    def loadFiles (self) :
        getDirectory            = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Browse', 'C:/')

        if getDirectory :
            fileList            = os.listdir (str(getDirectory))

            if fileList :
                self.listWidget.clear ()
                for eachFile in fileList :
                    self.listWidget.addItem (eachFile)        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

#Thanks, 
#Subin Gopi
```